# Pass base class to function delegate that recives the super class

Tags: c++, oop

I have this map:
`map<IEvent, EventHandler, IEventCompare>`
Where `EventHandler` is defined as `typedef void (*EventHandler)(IEvent);`

`IEvent` is a class that describes a general event.

Now I want to add to this map a function that receives `CreationEvent`, a class that inherits `IEvent`. The function is defined so:

`void onCreate(CreationEvent);`

But when I try to add it to the map, I get a compilation error

```
E0167 argument of type "void (Engine::IObject::*)(Engine::CreationEvent)" is incompatible with parameter of type "Engine::EventHandler"
```

And if I try to explicitly convert it to `EventHandler`:
`E0171 invalid type conversion`

I can declare `onCreate` with `IEvent`, but I would like to avoid it since it will require me to assume the type of event, and it is not well defined.

Is there a way to do what I try?

IEvent:

```
/**
    * Represents an Event, such as collision between 2 objects or click on an object.
    */
    class IEvent
    {
    public:
        IEvent(string name) { this->name = name; };
        /**
        * Copy constructor.
        */
        IEvent(const IEvent& other) { this->name = other.name;};

        string getName() const { return this->name; };

    protected:
        string name;
    };
```

CreationEvent:

```
class CreationEvent : public IEvent
    {
    public:
        CreationEvent();

        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> getCreateTime() const;

    private:
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> creationTime; /**< The creation time of this event.*/
    };
```

Notes:
Everything is inside namespace `Engine`, and the map is declared inside `IObject`.

Comment: Can you show us `IEvent` and `CreationEvent`?

Comment: No there is no way to do this. C++ simply does not work this way. This is one of the fundamental aspects of C++: strong type safety. If something is one type, it can only be set to objects of the same exact type. No exceptions. There are some explicit conversions that can happen, in several situations, but none of them apply in this case.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik thank you, I will search for some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your idea right, you want:

- Have typed events with base `event` class.
- Have handlers with base `handler` class.
- Handlers can receive event of certain type.

Consider the next example. For the simplicity I used `std::vector` instead of `std::map`, and put it inside event class.

**This code contains ugliness, leaks and must not be used in a "production" without modifications.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


//***********************************************************//
struct event;

struct handler
{

};

struct event_handler
{
    event_handler(handler* receiver) : receiver_{ receiver } {}
    handler* receiver_;
    virtual void invoke(event& evt) = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct event_handler_impl : event_handler
{
    typedef void (T::* handler_function)(U&);

    event_handler_impl(handler* receiver, handler_function function) :
        event_handler{ receiver_ },
        function_{ function } {}

    void invoke(event& evt) {
        T* typed_receiver = static_cast<T*>(receiver_);
        U& typed_event = static_cast<U&>(evt);
        (typed_receiver->*function_)(typed_event);
    }

    handler_function function_;
};

struct event
{
    void subscribe(event_handler* hdlr)
    {
        //TODO: Check. Is double added? 
        handlers_.push_back(hdlr);
    }

    void sent()
    {
        for (auto& item : handlers_)
        {
            item->invoke(*this);
        }
    }

    std::vector<event_handler*> handlers_;
};

//*****************************EXAMPLE***********************//

struct creation_event : public event
{
    int creation_id{};
};

struct bar_handler : public handler
{
    void handle_creation(creation_event& evt)
    {
        std::cout << "bar" << evt.creation_id << std::endl;
    }
};

struct foo_handler : public handler
{
    void handle_creation(creation_event& evt)
    {
        std::cout << "foo" << evt.creation_id << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
void subscribe_to_event(U& evt, T* reciver, void (T::* handler_function)(U&))
{
    evt.subscribe(new event_handler_impl<T, U>(reciver, handler_function));
}


int main()
{
    creation_event evt;
    bar_handler bar;
    foo_handler foo;


    subscribe_to_event(evt, &foo, &foo_handler::handle_creation);
    subscribe_to_event(evt, &bar, &bar_handler::handle_creation);


    evt.sent();
    evt.creation_id = 1;
    evt.sent();

    return 0;
}
```

The only tricky part is:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct event_handler_impl : event_handler
```

Here we generating classes for storing our typed “callback” and using polymorphism to store those classes inside our std::vector since they are all child classes for handler.

As a suggestion - consider using smart pointers instead of raw pointers. Also you can put function `void subscribe_to_even(…)` to the handler base class, so you can remove second parameter and just pass "this" to the event_handler_impl - `new event_handler_impl<T, U>(this, handler_function)`

Comment: This is not what I meant, but I think its far better. Thank you!